# how to reopen an activity on clicking/tapping notification

Tags: android

I am opening an activity on clicking notification. But if that activity is already open then I want to reopen that activity. From *reopen* I mean that; close that activity and open it again in order to display updated data. For doing that I am adding this line of code to intent of the notification:

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
```

But the problem is that when I click/tap notification, whole the application is closed instead of finishing only that activity. So please help.

Comment: You can reuse the same activity by defining android:launchmode="singleTop" or "singleInstance" in <activity> tag of Manifest file,so that you can use existing instance if it is already open

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can check if the `Activity` is already opened. I done this way

```
public static boolean FLAG=false;
```

in `onCreate` make it `true`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
FLAG=true;
.
.
}
```

now you can check this variable's value in the `Notification` class.

```
boolean isOpen=YourActivty.FLAG;
if(isOpen){
 //just clear the notification with adding the notification's data in the activity if you are sending to any listview or so. 
 //for adding the data to listview you need to make the `ArrayList`(i assume) and make a method in the adapter that will notify the adapter.
}else{
//call the Activity
}
```

Comment: this is good. but i want to make changes after the notification is clicked

Comment: what changes you want

Comment: I want to highlight an item of list view

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
         notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        Intent notificationIntent = null;
        notificationIntent = new Intent(context, SplashScreen.class);

        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
                | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);

        PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
                notificationIntent, 0);
        RemoteViews notiview = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(),
                R.layout.notification_layout);
        final NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                context).setSmallIcon(small_icon)
        // .setContentTitle(title)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                // .setStyle(
                // new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(message))
                .setDefaults(
                        Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND
                                | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE)
                // .setContentText(message).setNumber(noticount);
                .setContent(notiview);
        notiview.setTextViewText(R.id.noti_msgcount, "" + noticount);
        notiview.setTextViewText(R.id.noti_msgtxt, msgOld);

        mBuilder.setContentIntent(intent);
```